# When was the last bull & bear fight in California?

Tags: california, animals, sports

In 1700s and 1800s California, a popular form of entertainment was a fight to the death between a bull and a grizzly bear, either tied together or tied to a post. (This practice may have been Horace Greeley's inspiration for naming bull and bear markets.) The California Grizzly went extinct in the 1920s.

The last such fight in the town of Branciforte apparently [took place in July, 1867](http://www.santacruzsentinel.com/article/ZZ/20110624/NEWS/110627922). The San Mateo County Times-Gazette reported on one held in Castroville in September of the same year. Which fights, if any, came later?

[image]

Comment: An article about bear fights from 1911 stating that bears were common into the  early 1870s.  Does not state when fighting stopped.  http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85066387/1911-01-15/ed-1/seq-14/#date1=1789&index=2&date2=1925&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=bull+Bull+bulls+CALIFORNIA+California+fight+fights+grizzlies+GRIZZLIES+grizzly&proxdistance=5&state=&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=&andtext=grizzly+bull+california+fight&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1

Answer (score 3):

The last of these, *that we have record of*, seems to have occurred in 1880, in San Diego County.  This is hinted at by a couple of modern publications. The 1985 book *[*A Spaceship Called Earth: Our Living Environment*](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=DylFAAAAYAAJ&dq=bull%20and%20bear%20fight%20pala%20san%20diego%20county%201880&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=haynes)* mentions it, and though we only have the snippit view, it does hint at a primary source (emphasis mine):

> **The last one was at Pala, San Diego County, in 1880.**
>
> In the Haynes' book, a California pioneer, Major Horace Bell,
> described that supposedly last bear-bull fight at Pala. it pitted a
> grizzly captured on Palomar Mountain against four bulls in an
> adobe-walled arena. Bells' account went something like this...

If you want all the details, the [West of West](https://westofwestblog.wordpress.com/) blog site has an article [*Grizzly Battle at Pala*](https://westofwestblog.wordpress.com/grizzly-battle-at-pala-mission/) with the full story. The article does discuss the original source of the story, which was apparently published in [Horace Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horace_Bell)s' book  [*On the Old West Coast: Being Further Reminiscences of a Ranger*](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=CAcVAAAAYAAJ&dq=On%20the%20Old%20West%20Coast%3A%20Being%20Further%20Reminiscences%20of%20a%20Ranger&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=pala)

There is of course no way to guarantee this was the *last* of these *entertainments*, but it seems to be the last documented. The state of [California passed laws concerning animal fighting](https://books.google.com/books?id=64Y0AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA18-IA87&dq=california%201905%20laws%20bear%20bull%20fighting&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiY9eneqM_wAhXFl54KHUEkDDIQ6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=california%201905%20laws%20bear%20bull%20fighting&f=false) in 1905 (it was a misdemeanor):

> 8 Any person who shall cause any bull bear cock dog or other animal to
> fight for his amusement or for gain worry or injure each other or any
> person who shall permit the same to be done on any premises under his
> charge or control and any person who shall aid abet or be present at
> such fighting and worrying of such animal as a spectator shall upon
> conviction be deemed guilty of a misdemeanor

The last [California Grizzly Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_grizzly_bear#History_and_extinction) was killed in 1922.